# How to un/marshall underscored XML to/from camelcased Java using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

Strangely I couldn't find an existing question on this. I'm simply looking for a way (hopefully a one-liner) to do a programmatic conversion from e.g. `<sales_order_number>` to `salesOrderNumber`, and back again.

In Jackson terms, I'm looking for the JAXB equivalent of:

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy())
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Using the standard JAXB APIs you will need to use the JAXB annotations on individual properties to override the default name.

```
@XmlElement(name="sales_order_number")
private String salesOrderNumber;
```

MOXy provides am extension mechanism (`XMLNameTransformer`) where you can override the default name algorithm:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/overriding-jaxbs-name-mangling.html

Comment: Many thanks Blaise! I've posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629025/how-do-i-use-moxy-from-scala

Comment: @Blaise So I tried to get this to work in my project and the transformer is never activated. I've tried both package level and class level definitions. After that failed I tried to copy the example from your blog http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/overriding-jaxbs-name-mangling.html and this also failed. My environment uses Eclipselink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461 bundled w/Glassfish 3.1.2. It should work in that environment, right?

Comment: @Blaise I see XMLNameTransformer defines conversion from java to xml. But how can I define the opposite so I can unmarshall xml with funny casing?